AWS API Gateway configured for GET shows POST as Integration Method
I have configured API gate way with a GET Method.
screenshot
But when I export the stage config I see the integration method as POST.
    "paths" : {
    "/api/{proxy+}" : {
      "get" : {
        "parameters" : [ {
          "name" : "proxy",
          "in" : "path",
          "required" : true,
          "schema" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        } ],
        "responses" : {
          "200" : {
            "description" : "200 response",
            "content" : {
              "application/json" : {
                "schema" : {
                  "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/Empty"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration" : {
          **"type" : "aws_proxy",
          "httpMethod" : "POST",**
          "uri" : "arn:aws:apigateway:ap-south-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:233646325951:function:admingui/invocations",
          "responses" : {
            "default" : {
              "statusCode" : "200"
            }
          },
          "passthroughBehavior" : "when_no_match",
          "cacheNamespace" : "i2ndmg",
          "cacheKeyParameters" : [ "method.request.path.proxy" ],
          "contentHandling" : "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
        }
      },



I thought this should be a GET or am I missing some thing here?
Not sure if this is normal or a BUG?

This is expected for any {proxy+} endpoints.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-any-method.html
